# merge ALMOST duplicate records IN sql

Tags: sql-server, merge

Greeting all...

i have two table and their structure is identical...

Table logDetail

```
Date              Time         CardID        Status  
2012-01-20        00:00:00     A1            ABSENT
2012-01-20        00:00:00     B1            ABSENT
2012-01-20        00:00:00     C3            ABSENT
2012-01-20        00:00:00     D1            ABSENT
```

Table preStatus

```
Date            Time        CardID        Status
2012-01-20     07:00:10     A1            COMING
2012-01-20     07:10:00     C3            COMING
2012-01-20     08:00:00     B1            LATE
2012-01-20     17:00:00     B1            BACK
2012-01-20     17:10:10     A1            BACK
2012-01-20     17:13:00     C3            BACK
```

After Merge

```
Date
2012-01-20     07:00:10     A1            COMING
2012-01-20     07:10:00     C3            COMING
2012-01-20     08:00:00     B1            LATE
2012-01-20     00:00:00     D1            ABSENT
2012-01-20     17:00:00     B1            BACK
2012-01-20     17:10:10     A1            BACK
2012-01-20     17:13:00     C3            BACK
```

How may i merge these two table because in table b there is duplicate records and when i do 
a merge...

```
merge into logDetail as Target 
using preStatus as Source
on Target.L_Date=Source.L_Date
and Target.L_Time='00:00:00'
and Target.L_CardID=Source.L_CardID 
when matched then

update set Target.L_Status=Source.L_Status,
Target.L_Time=Source.L_Time
when not matched then
insert (L_Date,L_Time,L_CardID,L_Status) 
                           values(Source.L_Date,Source.L_Time,Source.L_CardID,Source.L_Status);
```

it said The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `c#` tag doesn't seem relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to want to merge the tables, since CardID is not a primary key.

It looks like you want to retain the entries where Status = "COMING" even when there are new entries where stats = "BACK".

I suggest you do this in two steps, first do inserts of the preStatus data, then delete "ABSENT" rows where there exists "COMING" and "BACK" rows.

```
/* Insert new data */
insert logDetail
select * from preStatus

/* Delete Absent rows where there is a COMING or BACK row for the same item on the same day */
Delete logDetail
from logDetail ld1
where 
    /* Absent rows only */
    ld1.time = '00:00:00'
and ld1.Status = 'ABSENT'
/*  And there must be a COMING or BACK row for the same card on the same day */
and exists (
   select 1 from logDetail ld2
   where ld2.Date = ld1.Date
   and ld2.CardID = ld1.CardID
   and ld2.Time > '00:00:00'
   and ld2.Status <> 'ABSENT'
)
```

To remove rows for the same Date, CardID, and same Status, but where there is a later Time:

```
Delete logDetail
from logDetail ld1
where 
ld1.status in ('COMING', 'BACK')
/*  COMING or BACK row only */ 
      /* for the same card on the same day, with a later time*/
and exists (
   select 1 from logDetail ld2
   where ld2.Date = ld1.Date      
   and ld2.CardID = ld1.CardID
   and ld2.Status = ld1.Status
   and ld2.Time > ld1.Time
)
```

Comment: The two steps should probably be done as a single transaction, to rectify the loss of `MERGE`'s atomicity.

Comment: The second step is idempotent, i.e. it can be repeated without changing the result, and also will have no effect if the first step fails.

Comment: thanks Ben and everyone...it works like charm! but i have another to ask...if i want to remove almost duplicate record, how to do it...for example i have two records, but the different only at the column time..and i want to keep only the oldest record and remove the other...how is it people?

Comment: @ApizZest, see revised answer.

Comment: thanks again Ben...that's very helpful to me! I have one outside the topic question-type here...if i change or migrate from mssql into mysql, do these all queries still valid?

Answer (score 0):

Do not do anything when matched, this should solve it?

Comment: im having problem with this sentence "The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once" it refers to the table preStatus because it appear that the sql does not know which record to update...thats my real problem...any idea?